# Pushing objects into an array in Javascript after extracting from JSON response

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to push objects into an array of objects. The code I have written repeats the last index value for all indices in the array. Any help regarding what I might be doing wrong would be great.

CODE:

```
var comment = {
Comment_ID : "",
Text_Displayed : ""
};

var comments = [];
var total = 4;
var i;

for(i = 0 ; i < total ; i++){
 comment.Comment_ID = json1.items[i].snippet.topLevelComment.id ;
 comment.Text_Displayed = json1.items[i].snippet.topLevelComment.snippet.textDisplay ;
 comments.push(comment);
}
```

json1 is the raw JSON response.
I have tried parsing it using JSON.parse(json1) and thus converting it to a Javascript object, however, doing so, my array remains empty.

json1 :

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#commentThreadListResponse",
  "etag": "DdP0Qpu15x6rNWi8DqdtP8XHFWk",
  "nextPageToken": "QURTSl9pMHRqeTI4QzlFdG9mdE44MFloNlhrS1hJS3FLSFgwS2FhM3gzaVZ0QzU5SS1KdVBJNkdXUWF6OU1Qdm85OFJwdUJuZG4xR2dLRFR1bkltWTRuZVdfR1NaaWFtaXMxVDVtQUxCQUV0LURLRlEwMnJFWVVodkhpN3RnUUJDR1U=",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 4,
    "resultsPerPage": 4
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#commentThread",
      "etag": "7p4LroRwZP3DTt8DuMTZoPB8WFE",
      "id": "UgyHbtFESKXeYdHptoN4AaABAg",
      "snippet": {
        "videoId": "M7FIvfx5J10",
        "topLevelComment": {
          "kind": "youtube#comment",
          "etag": "l7TPuxvp3y-HuT7pUTFuilRsbCo",
          "id": "UgyHbtFESKXeYdHptoN4AaABAg",
          "snippet": {
            "videoId": "M7FIvfx5J10",
            "textDisplay": "I come from the distant future and this is still the best commercial ever made",
            "textOriginal": "I come from the distant future and this is still the best commercial ever made",
            "authorDisplayName": "Max Haugen",
            "authorProfileImageUrl": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJxruw_9hJGB8nS4D2yu2j8Z-SuZ9whhaeeF1w=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo",
            "authorChannelUrl": "http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCmmmb4WuHKWaXOIM5W7CNPg",
            "authorChannelId": {
              "value": "UCmmmb4WuHKWaXOIM5W7CNPg"
            },
            "canRate": true,
            "viewerRating": "none",
            "likeCount": 0,
            "publishedAt": "2020-05-27T15:18:30Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-05-27T15:18:30Z"
          }
        },
        "canReply": true,
        "totalReplyCount": 0,
        "isPublic": true
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#commentThread",
      "etag": "_gONUvfm77ZziX2qXYqMLG5ZrNY",
      "id": "UgxBfriPiiexMxJSnht4AaABAg",
      "snippet": {
        "videoId": "M7FIvfx5J10",
        "topLevelComment": {
          "kind": "youtube#comment",
          "etag": "6JGrrdeWCJstQ5-oN8Ll5uRxptw",
          "id": "UgxBfriPiiexMxJSnht4AaABAg",
          "snippet": {
            "videoId": "M7FIvfx5J10",
            "textDisplay": "I remember doing something similar for an English assignment back in school. What an ad",
            "textOriginal": "I remember doing something similar for an English assignment back in school. What an ad",
            "authorDisplayName": "Driving Channel",
            "authorProfileImageUrl": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJzENHoGlkmsCBbxxfoYWlnbdXVJR_B-H_FuVQ=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo",
            "authorChannelUrl": "http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCF2FnoRbunwPE17Z7sB-4FQ",
            "authorChannelId": {
              "value": "UCF2FnoRbunwPE17Z7sB-4FQ"
            },
            "canRate": true,
            "viewerRating": "none",
            "likeCount": 0,
            "publishedAt": "2020-05-27T14:27:17Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-05-27T14:27:17Z"
          }
        },
        "canReply": true,
        "totalReplyCount": 0,
        "isPublic": true
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#commentThread",
      "etag": "2UZe_rxTkfikNASd6SJL_dIm3XU",
      "id": "UgzdU_BTVF6gVN3UeTh4AaABAg",
      "snippet": {
        "videoId": "M7FIvfx5J10",
        "topLevelComment": {
          "kind": "youtube#comment",
          "etag": "JRkp__giuGwRMX7OL-_jun2XvAU",
          "id": "UgzdU_BTVF6gVN3UeTh4AaABAg",
          "snippet": {
            "videoId": "M7FIvfx5J10",
            "textDisplay": "still the best ad ever created",
            "textOriginal": "still the best ad ever created",
            "authorDisplayName": "Mika Baggins",
            "authorProfileImageUrl": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJyUa2bJbuPGlW7fzBh8BmwdaHsjfxX2n7jUvA=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo",
            "authorChannelUrl": "http://www.youtube.com/channel/UC8ydLvFnROzrIf_w60VNJuA",
            "authorChannelId": {
              "value": "UC8ydLvFnROzrIf_w60VNJuA"
            },
            "canRate": true,
            "viewerRating": "none",
            "likeCount": 0,
            "publishedAt": "2020-05-26T20:33:47Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-05-26T20:33:47Z"
          }
        },
        "canReply": true,
        "totalReplyCount": 0,
        "isPublic": true
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#commentThread",
      "etag": "FIlRkfyxEh1b94jwmiCBBvw8Zrk",
      "id": "UgyJJo90JtuEgL65VTh4AaABAg",
      "snippet": {
        "videoId": "M7FIvfx5J10",
        "topLevelComment": {
          "kind": "youtube#comment",
          "etag": "fj-xjtD4g21_zw4XGt9sEIG3b_Q",
          "id": "UgyJJo90JtuEgL65VTh4AaABAg",
          "snippet": {
            "videoId": "M7FIvfx5J10",
            "textDisplay": "I like it tooooooo much !!!!!!!",
            "textOriginal": "I like it tooooooo much !!!!!!!",
            "authorDisplayName": "В НАТУРАШКУ",
            "authorProfileImageUrl": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJyzs1NscDCXF_n7TnaAhkqEujQCQGHVjkabsg=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo",
            "authorChannelUrl": "http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCzKl3D_2Mp25PQjVnI7zrqQ",
            "authorChannelId": {
              "value": "UCzKl3D_2Mp25PQjVnI7zrqQ"
            },
            "canRate": true,
            "viewerRating": "none",
            "likeCount": 0,
            "publishedAt": "2020-05-26T19:08:59Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-05-26T19:08:59Z"
          }
        },
        "canReply": true,
        "totalReplyCount": 0,
        "isPublic": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: how does json1 looks like?

Comment: We will need to see what json1 is to debug this. You can `console.log(json1)` to see it.

Comment: You have to define `var i = 0` and a new `var comment` on each iteration

Comment: Do you see any errors in the debugger? Have you debugged your code to see where it fails?

Comment: @dehart, declaring a new ```var comment``` in the loop worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If comments is indeed a json object, then you might be far easier of to map the response to the array you need, for example by doing:

```
const comments = response.items.map( comment => ({ 
  commentId: comment.snippet.topLevelComment.id, 
  text: comment.snippet.topLevelComment.snippet.textDisplay }) 
);
```

This will map all the `items` in the `response` object into a newly created comments array.

```js
const response = {
  "kind": "youtube#commentThreadListResponse",
  "etag": "DdP0Qpu15x6rNWi8DqdtP8XHFWk",
  "nextPageToken": "QURTSl9pMHRqeTI4QzlFdG9mdE44MFloNlhrS1hJS3FLSFgwS2FhM3gzaVZ0QzU5SS1KdVBJNkdXUWF6OU1Qdm85OFJwdUJuZG4xR2dLRFR1bkltWTRuZVdfR1NaaWFtaXMxVDVtQUxCQUV0LURLRlEwMnJFWVVodkhpN3RnUUJDR1U=",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 4,
    "resultsPerPage": 4
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#commentThread",
      "etag": "7p4LroRwZP3DTt8DuMTZoPB8WFE",
      "id": "UgyHbtFESKXeYdHptoN4AaABAg",
      "snippet": {
        "videoId": "M7FIvfx5J10",
        "topLevelComment": {
          "kind": "youtube#comment",
          "etag": "l7TPuxvp3y-HuT7pUTFuilRsbCo",
          "id": "UgyHbtFESKXeYdHptoN4AaABAg",
          "snippet": {
            "videoId": "M7FIvfx5J10",
            "textDisplay": "I come from the distant future and this is still the best commercial ever made",
            "textOriginal": "I come from the distant future and this is still the best commercial ever made",
            "authorDisplayName": "Max Haugen",
            "authorProfileImageUrl": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJxruw_9hJGB8nS4D2yu2j8Z-SuZ9whhaeeF1w=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo",
            "authorChannelUrl": "http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCmmmb4WuHKWaXOIM5W7CNPg",
            "authorChannelId": {
              "value": "UCmmmb4WuHKWaXOIM5W7CNPg"
            },
            "canRate": true,
            "viewerRating": "none",
            "likeCount": 0,
            "publishedAt": "2020-05-27T15:18:30Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-05-27T15:18:30Z"
          }
        },
        "canReply": true,
        "totalReplyCount": 0,
        "isPublic": true
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#commentThread",
      "etag": "_gONUvfm77ZziX2qXYqMLG5ZrNY",
      "id": "UgxBfriPiiexMxJSnht4AaABAg",
      "snippet": {
        "videoId": "M7FIvfx5J10",
        "topLevelComment": {
          "kind": "youtube#comment",
          "etag": "6JGrrdeWCJstQ5-oN8Ll5uRxptw",
          "id": "UgxBfriPiiexMxJSnht4AaABAg",
          "snippet": {
            "videoId": "M7FIvfx5J10",
            "textDisplay": "I remember doing something similar for an English assignment back in school. What an ad",
            "textOriginal": "I remember doing something similar for an English assignment back in school. What an ad",
            "authorDisplayName": "Driving Channel",
            "authorProfileImageUrl": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJzENHoGlkmsCBbxxfoYWlnbdXVJR_B-H_FuVQ=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo",
            "authorChannelUrl": "http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCF2FnoRbunwPE17Z7sB-4FQ",
            "authorChannelId": {
              "value": "UCF2FnoRbunwPE17Z7sB-4FQ"
            },
            "canRate": true,
            "viewerRating": "none",
            "likeCount": 0,
            "publishedAt": "2020-05-27T14:27:17Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-05-27T14:27:17Z"
          }
        },
        "canReply": true,
        "totalReplyCount": 0,
        "isPublic": true
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#commentThread",
      "etag": "2UZe_rxTkfikNASd6SJL_dIm3XU",
      "id": "UgzdU_BTVF6gVN3UeTh4AaABAg",
      "snippet": {
        "videoId": "M7FIvfx5J10",
        "topLevelComment": {
          "kind": "youtube#comment",
          "etag": "JRkp__giuGwRMX7OL-_jun2XvAU",
          "id": "UgzdU_BTVF6gVN3UeTh4AaABAg",
          "snippet": {
            "videoId": "M7FIvfx5J10",
            "textDisplay": "still the best ad ever created",
            "textOriginal": "still the best ad ever created",
            "authorDisplayName": "Mika Baggins",
            "authorProfileImageUrl": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJyUa2bJbuPGlW7fzBh8BmwdaHsjfxX2n7jUvA=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo",
            "authorChannelUrl": "http://www.youtube.com/channel/UC8ydLvFnROzrIf_w60VNJuA",
            "authorChannelId": {
              "value": "UC8ydLvFnROzrIf_w60VNJuA"
            },
            "canRate": true,
            "viewerRating": "none",
            "likeCount": 0,
            "publishedAt": "2020-05-26T20:33:47Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-05-26T20:33:47Z"
          }
        },
        "canReply": true,
        "totalReplyCount": 0,
        "isPublic": true
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#commentThread",
      "etag": "FIlRkfyxEh1b94jwmiCBBvw8Zrk",
      "id": "UgyJJo90JtuEgL65VTh4AaABAg",
      "snippet": {
        "videoId": "M7FIvfx5J10",
        "topLevelComment": {
          "kind": "youtube#comment",
          "etag": "fj-xjtD4g21_zw4XGt9sEIG3b_Q",
          "id": "UgyJJo90JtuEgL65VTh4AaABAg",
          "snippet": {
            "videoId": "M7FIvfx5J10",
            "textDisplay": "I like it tooooooo much !!!!!!!",
            "textOriginal": "I like it tooooooo much !!!!!!!",
            "authorDisplayName": "В НАТУРАШКУ",
            "authorProfileImageUrl": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJyzs1NscDCXF_n7TnaAhkqEujQCQGHVjkabsg=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo",
            "authorChannelUrl": "http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCzKl3D_2Mp25PQjVnI7zrqQ",
            "authorChannelId": {
              "value": "UCzKl3D_2Mp25PQjVnI7zrqQ"
            },
            "canRate": true,
            "viewerRating": "none",
            "likeCount": 0,
            "publishedAt": "2020-05-26T19:08:59Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-05-26T19:08:59Z"
          }
        },
        "canReply": true,
        "totalReplyCount": 0,
        "isPublic": true
      }
    }
  ]
};

const comments = response.items.map( comment => ({ commentId: comment.snippet.topLevelComment.id, text: comment.snippet.topLevelComment.snippet.textDisplay }) );

console.log( comments );
```

If we look at the code you provided, there are some things you need to be careful with, albeit I get that it's probably a simpler version than the actual code you have

The declaration and initialization of comment shouldn't be kept out of the scope of array, as you intend to use it. If you do it this way, and the array would fill, all comments would refer to the one single object, and would have the same properties (it stays always the same reference)

```
var comment = {
  Comment_ID : "",
  Text_Displayed : ""
};
```

You define total to be a hardcoded 4, and while this might currently work, you have better options at hand. An array has a `length` property, so it seems better to use that one instead

```
const total = json1.items.length;
```

`i` will only be used in the for-loop, so you might as well declare it there only, thus, it becomes something like this (with a rework how you could add the comments without re-using a variable)

```
for( let i = 0 ; i < total ; i++) {
  comments.push({
    Comment_ID: json1.items[i].snippet.topLevelComment.id,
    Text_Displayed: json1.items[i].snippet.topLevelComment.snippet.textDisplay
  });
}
```

however, you still have the index accesses, and this you could for go by using the map I showed you, or by using a `for..of` loop like:

```
for( let comment of json1.items ) {
  comments.push({
    Comment_ID: comment.snippet.topLevelComment.id,
    Text_Displayed: comment.snippet.topLevelComment.snippet.textDisplay
  });
}
```

Thus making your code a little bit more readable. You undoubtedly noticed the usage of `let` & `const` keywords throughout my changes. They were introduced in JS 2015 (I think, have to follow up) and they are really worthy to use. `var` should be avoided whenever possible, as `let` & `const` are there to rectify the scope problems that the `var` keyword carries

Comment: Thank you Icepickle. Comments is just a normal object here.

Comment: @Viktor, I tried to add more information about the code you provided as well, but as to your comment, what do you mean with comments being only a normal object? If you refer to my usage of `const` it just implies that the variable shouldn't be reassigned anymore (you can still modify it's contents, just not reassign a completely new object to it)

Comment: Thanks. 
I am new to JS. So by a normal object, I just mean any object such as ```var a = {field1 : "value1" , field2 :"value2"}; ```

What would I have done differently if it were a JSON string parsed into a Javascript object using the JSON.parse(json1) method?

Comment: @Victor I think once you finished your program, and you are allowed to share, you might have a lot to learn from having a [codereview.se]. Do read their policy on questions and how to ask first, though :)